# how can use Nesk\Puphpeteer for click and type in (input or element) using ID and Class like puppeteer in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, puppeteer, puphpeteer

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;
    use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
    use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Resources\ElementHandle;

class test{

    public function startElement(){
    $puppeteer = new Puppeteer();
    $browser = $puppeteer->launch([
        'headless' =>false,
        'executablePath' =>"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
        'defaultViewport'=> null,
        'args'=> ['--lang=en-ru']
    ]);

    $page = $browser->newPage();
    $page->setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); 

        $page->goto('URL');

    $page->waitForTimeout(1000);

        $username = $page->querySelector('#UserName');
        $username->focus();
        $page->keyboard->type('username'); 

    $page->waitForTimeout(500);

        $password = $page->querySelector('#Password');
        $password->type('password');

        $btn = $page->querySelector('.btn.btn-default');  
        $btn->focus();
        $page->keyboard->press('Enter'); 

    $page->waitForTimeout(5000);
    
    header("Location: ../index.php?Input=SUCCESS");
    }
}
?>
```

I tried to use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Resources\ElementHandle;

so that I can click or type on element or input as it is done on puppeteer nodejs,

when I run the code it doesn’t give me an error, but it can’t find this element on the page (the element is correct, I tried it on puppeteer nodejs everything worked correctly)
I saw in some codes on Nesk\Puphpeteer that they use class and public, I added them and the code did not run and does not give any errors. how can i fix this